# Text box next to an image

Tags: html, css

I want to have an orange box next to the image, like this:

[image]

I know how to add the image and the orange box, but I don't understand how I can get them next to each other. Below you'll find my HTML and CSS.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
}

.image {
  float: left;
}

.box {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contents">
    <div>
      <p>Actualmente se encuentra en:</p>
      <p>
        <a href="index.html">Lion</a>
        <p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://7art-screensavers.com/screenshots/animals/lying-lion.jpg" alt="Lion">
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <h2>León de Áfric</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, nemo. Consequatur quod rerum reiciendis, laborum, ex, accusamus atque fugiat dicta aperiam commodi adipisci impedit animi. Non impedit, reprehenderit eius dolor.</p>
        <p>
          <a href="elephant.html">Siguiente »</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many ways - floats, tables, flexbox, grids - which browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used flexbox to align the boxes as desired and removed the floats.

```css
.wrapper{
 width:1000px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.content{
 height:1000px;
 width:1000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contents">
    <div>
      <p>Actualmente se encuentra en:</p>
      <p>
        <a href="index.html">Lion</a>
        <p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="Lion">
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <h2>León de Áfric</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, nemo. Consequatur quod rerum reiciendis, laborum, ex, accusamus atque fugiat dicta aperiam commodi adipisci impedit animi. Non impedit, reprehenderit eius dolor.</p>
        <p>
          <a href="elephant.html">Siguiente »</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Padding or margin would be nice

Comment: Yeah sure. So would an orange background, actual image of a lion, correct font etc etc. But the question was how to align the two boxes next to each other. This is one of the possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.wrapper{
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.content{
  height:1000px;
  width:1000px;
}

.image{
  float:left;
  width:60%;
}
.image img{
  max-width:100%;
}
.box{
  float:right;
  width:40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contents">
    <div>
      <p>Actualmente se encuentra en:</p>
      <p>
        <a href="index.html">Lion</a>
      <p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/71/9a/a0/719aa07e7ccc325fd05b933eea027dec.jpg" alt="Lion">
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <h2>León de Áfric</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, nemo. Consequatur quod rerum reiciendis, laborum, ex, accusamus atque fugiat dicta aperiam commodi adipisci impedit animi. Non impedit, reprehenderit eius dolor.</p>
        <p>
          <a href="elephant.html">Siguiente »</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` to get it

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}

.image {
  flex: 8 0 0;
}

.box {
  flex: 2 0 0;
  background: orange;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contents">
    <div>
      <p>Actualmente se encuentra en:</p>
      <p>
        <a href="index.html">Lion</a>
        <p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="http://7art-screensavers.com/screenshots/animals/lying-lion.jpg" alt="Lion">
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <h2>León de Áfric</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, nemo. Consequatur quod rerum reiciendis, laborum, ex, accusamus atque fugiat dicta aperiam commodi adipisci impedit animi. Non impedit, reprehenderit eius dolor.</p>
        <p>
          <a href="elephant.html">Siguiente »</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```